# Why mark-compact is slower than mark-copy?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

There is a saying that mark-compact is slower than mark-copy. But why? As both algorithm need to move living objects.

Comment: Can you refer to a particular source saying that?

Answer (score 3):

As with just about anything to do with garbage collection, it is complicated.

The intuitive reasoning is that mark compact requires an extra pass across all objects (reachable AND unreachable) to find the reachable objects that need to be compacted.  In addition, it is (often) more work to fix up pointers in objects during compaction than during a from-space to to-space copy.  (Or if you don't compact, you pay performance penalties in other areas.)

However, in *"Garbage Collection: Algorithms for Automatic Dynamic Memory Management"*, Jones and Lins present a theoretical analysis which shows that the relative efficiency of mark-sweep versus single generation copying collectors depends on the "residency" (r) of your application; i.e. the ratio of live data to the heap size.  Above a certain residency r<sup>*</sup>, mark-sweep is more efficient.

(Note that r<sup>*</sup> will be less than 0.5.  A single generation copying collector only works for r less than 0.5.)

If you really want to understand, I recommend that you buy the book.  Or better still, the more recent, *"The Garbage Collection Handbook: The Art of Automatic Memory Management"* by Jones, Hosking and Moss.